# How to get fetcher.Form values in remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix, remix.run

Im using useFetcher() to create a form via <fetcher.Form>. I have several input fields throughout the form, but I do not want the form to be submitted when the user hits the enter key. To do so, on form submission I have a form handler that calls e.preventDefault(). I want the form to be submitted via an explicit user action (clicking a Save button. I assumed that in order to submit the form manually I would call fetcher.submit(), but I need the forms values to do so, but the fetcher hook doesnt seem to provide a way of getting them. I cant figure out an easy way to get the forms values to do the submission without creating controlled input fields, which defeats the whole purpose of using <fetcher.Form>. Is the solution to just create a whole form with controlled inputs or am I missing something?

```
const fetcher = useFetcher():

function submitHandler(e: FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function realSubmit(){
    // let formData = fetcher.data;
    let formData = ""; // how do I get the form data??

    fetcher.submit(formData, fetcher.formAction);
}

return(
    <fetcher.Form action="/some/route" onSubmit={submitHandler} method="post">
        <input name="input1" type="text"/>
        <input name="input2" type="text"/>
        <input name="input3" type="text"/>
     
        <button type="submit" onClick={realSubmit}>Save</button>
    </fetcher.Form>
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to create a form `ref`. Then you can create a `FormData` object from the ref and submit it.

```js
export default function Index() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  function submitHandler(e: FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function realSubmit() {    
    const formData = new FormData(formRef.current!);
    // modify formData here
    formData.set("message", "hello world")
    fetcher.submit(formData);
  }

  return (
    <fetcher.Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={submitHandler} method="post">
      <input name="input1" type="text" />
      <input name="input2" type="text" />
      <input name="input3" type="text" />

      <button type="submit" onClick={realSubmit}>
        Save
      </button>
    </fetcher.Form>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**: Another option is to keep the regular submit handler.

```js
export default function Index() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  function submitHandler(e: FormEvent) {
    // get formData from currentTarget (form)
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

    // modify formData here
    formData.set("message", "hello world")

    // submit formData using fetcher
    fetcher.submit(formData);

    // prevent default form submit
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <fetcher.Form onSubmit={submitHandler} method="post">
      <input name="input1" type="text" />
      <input name="input2" type="text" />
      <input name="input3" type="text" />

      <button type="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </fetcher.Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: For your first example, I noticed that it still submits if the button is within the form body. When I move it outside of the form body it works as expected. I think its because both the submitHandler and realSubmit methods get called. This isn't an issue, because I want the submit button to be outside of the form, but its a behavior that wasn't obvious to me.